# Why are Vapor GET requests being processed in the URL

Tags: swift, vapor

I am creating a Vapor server, but it is processing GET requests in the URL, when enter is not being pressed. See below for an example:

Suppose I have the code `get('hello')`, and whenever it is entered, it returns hello world in `json` format.

If I were to run the Vapor server, type `localhost:8080/hello`, and press enter in my browser, it will return `{"hello":"world"}`, which works as intended. On the console, it will print `GET /hello`, which works as intended. However, if I was to clear hello from the URL, I would have `localhost:8080/` the output would be empty, printing `GET /` to the console. If I were to then append h to this: `localhost:8080/h`, then the URL will autocomplete to `localhost:8080/hello` because I entered it earlier, printing `GET /hello` to the console, before I have pressed enter in the URL.

Whenever I type text into the URL, it is sending a request to the Vapor server, and processing the request - even if I don't press enter to send the request.

Why is it doing this, and how can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2):

Safari (and probably some other browsers) uses a pre-fetching feature. See 'Preload Top Hit in the background' in the Search section of Safari preferences. If enabled, your browser will send off `GET` requests at various times without your even being aware of it.

You can't stop this behaviour in the wide world, so you need to plan for it. `GET` endpoints shouldn't do any significant work, or change any model state. Put those sorts of endpoints behind a verb like `POST`.

Comment: I'm guessing the best way to test GET requests is with specific programs, such as Postman, to test this - since only my app will be sending requests to the server that is on the cloud.